# How to put the 'assign to new user' select when you delete a user that has custom post type posts, but no normal posts

Tags: users

A client wants to delete some of his users, but since those users have posts of custom post type, but no blogposts per say, the select to reassign the posts to someone else doesn't appear.

Is there a way to force that select to appear?

Comment: WordPress will display that option if the user is the author of any posts of any type. Not just blog posts. Are you sure those users are actually assigned as the _author_ or the posts you want to reassign? Or are they attached in some other way?

Comment: Think the bug is that these users theorically don't have to right to own a post, but the code does assign it to them.

Comment: Assign how though? If they’re not specifically the `post_author` then this feature won’t work, and you’ll need to implement it yourself.

Comment: They are the post author, but in the select, others with the same role do not appear (they are all subscribers) So, well, they are the author, but don't have the right to be one. I guess the select checks mostly 'can this user own a post' and that is No. Even if it does.

Comment: (All of this is created posts via a front end form, that assigns the author programmatically.)